# Load emacs desktop-plus session from command line?

Tags: bash, emacs

I am trying to make a bash alia to cd into the project directory and open emacs with a specific desktop loaded via "M-x desktop-load " (desktop-load command is from desktop-plus). Is there a way to specify a desktop from the command line? Maybe something like this:

```
$ cd Sites/my.site.com && emacs --desktop-load=my.site.com-desktop-name
```

Thanks!

Comment: An alternative, if you would like to easily switch desktops from within Emacs (instead of the command line), is to use [*desktop bookmarks*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks). For that you need library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). I don't offer it as an *answer* here because you specifically asked for a command-line solution (although you could of course invoke a bookmark from the command line).

Comment: Thanks, although I usually (simultaneously) use a separate Terminal window with a couple of tabs for each project so my question does indeed still stand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write a simple Elisp function to do what you want, and invoke Emacs with `--eval`.  The expression you pass in can be arbitrarily complex, so you could do

```
emd () {
   cd $HOME/Sites/"$1" &&
   emacs --eval "(progn (require 'desktop+) (desktop-load \"$1-desktop-name\"))" &
}
```

but perhaps encapsulating the Lisp form into a simple `.el` file would be preferable.

Shell functions are generally preferable to aliases and using a command-line argument like this is not possible in an alias.

Comment: However, as @Drew is gently suggesting, the usual way to run Emacs is to start it once, then live inside that session until you shut down your computer.

Comment: Nice, it looks like --eval is the answer for me. Yeah, I would love to be in single-window mode, and I'll be there in the future. Even though I've been using emacs for 17 years at a moderate-novice level, there is still a jump in skill level needed to be able to do one session per day (or ever). Any suggestions on particular accelerated no-fluff learning sources?

Comment: We are close here, but the only problem is that "(require 'desktop-plus)" is (maybe?) not required, and then desktop-load doesn't take a string parameter but instead prompts for the desktop name. Is that a problem or is there another way to change the command line?

Comment: Did you try? Usually, Lisp functions which prompt when invoked interactively can be invoked programmatically with an argument. And the `require` will simply no-op if the library is already loaded, so it's safe to include as a robustness measure.

Comment: I did try it but must have made a mistake because it worked after trying again just now (although I had to remove the require call since the package is spelled incorrectly and already loaded). Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep, that one. Funny that it wasn't finding it on my machine.

Comment: I can confirm that the `require` form isn't needed since `desktop-load` should be autoloaded. But it shouldn't hurt either, as @tripleee noted.